# Show loading screen when fetching images

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, assets

Let's say I have images stored on AWS bucket and react app with router (7 pages). Every page have some images pointed to AWS specific link. I tried to preload them with some third party library (like react-proggresive-images etc.), but it looks not good to see blurred version, so I decided to show loaders instead of pixel-blurred image. But I Have different styles applied to images, so I need to fix loader placement, styles too. Right now I wanna show one general loader instead of rendered page, and while images are loading - it shows that loader. When all images on different pages with defferent AWS links are fetched, then I can show my rendered content (like this example - http://stefaniebrueckler.com/) I'm using React. redux, Mui v5, typescript. Thank you for attention.

Comment: Right now I added Custom component called <ProgressiveImage> which returns loader when fetching image and later replaces this loader. Also I added similar component for blurred images insted of loaders (if fixes problem with styles)

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a example. This is not enough information to help you properly with your question. In general it sounds like you need to implement a kind of global state (React Context API, Redux, zustand or something similar) or work with standard props, passing them back and forth, to manage the loading states of your images. When all your images are loaded, you stop displaying your loader.

Comment: What information ? It is a general question. as written up here, I have just simple image urls (like <img src={url}>), and each of image have custom url pointing to AWS bucket. I just wanna preload all of them and then render the actul app. I am not passing them via props, storing in redux, context etc. Risght now I'm showing loaders through custom image component, but as I said, it's bad for styles. So the question is: "how can I preload all images and then show my app" (you can give me some link, ideas whatever it is - just in declarative way. The imperative way will be done by me)

Comment: You therefore need a way to know if a image has been loaded and show your general loader until every image has been loaded. That's why i was suggesting working with stores. You could make use of the `onLoad` eventhandler or a more hacky way would be to use the `window.onload` eventhandler.